# AngularJS does not create new object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

i write a simple angularJS code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('BooksController', function($scope){
      $scope.books = [{'name':'aaa'}, {'name':'bbb'}, {'name':'ccc'}];
      $scope.addBook = function(newBook){
          $scope.books.push(newBook);
      }
    });
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="BooksController">
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="book in books">{{book.name}}</li>
      </ul>
      <input ng-model=aBook.name />
      <a href=# ng-click="addBook(aBook)">add to list</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EIT32t8NgRiLchVXgooL?p=preview

when i add a new item to the list, it works correctly.
but when i want to add another new item, the last item overwrite as you can see in the url. **why? what happen?**

Comment: Shouldn't it be:
ng-model="book.name"
instead of:
ng-model=aBook.name

Comment: @Manube No, renaming `aBook` to `book` doesn't solve the problem as you can test at the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$scope.addBook = function(newBook){
    $scope.books.push(angular.copy(newBook));
}
```

> why? what happen?

This happens because your input is bound to book's name, when you are adding book in array, same object instance is added, so binding is still happening.

before addBook()

```
$scope.books = [{'name':'aaa'}, {'name':'bbb'}, {'name':'ccc'}];
```

after addBook()

```
$scope.books = [{'name':'aaa'}, {'name':'bbb'}, {'name':'ccc'}, aBook];
```

With angular.copy we are creating another instance of book object with same property values

Comment: ok. so i prefer to empty the object of scope after add: `$scope.books.push(newBook);$scope.aBook={};`
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.addBook = function(newBook){
      $scope.books.push($scope.newbook);
      $scope.newbook={"name":""};
      $scope.$apply();
  }
  $scope.newbook={"name":""};
```

and

```
<input ng-model="newbook.name" type="text">
  <a href=# ng-click="addBook()">add</a>
```

will work;

> but when i want to add another new item, the last item overwrite as you can see in the url. why? what happen?

that's because a newbook has to be created right after insertion, with:

```
$scope.newbook={"name":""};
```

otherwise you will keep inserting/modifying the same item

Comment: i deleted my previous 'answer', as it was more a comment than anything else, as suggested by jsve

Comment: ok. so i prefer to empty the object of scope after add: `$scope.books.push(newBook);$scope.aBook={};`
thanks.